# Interactive legend in aChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine, legend, interactive

I have implemented bar charts and pie charts in my Android app with the library aChartEngine.

I want to know if I can interact with the graph, that is, if when I click on a title of the legend the corresponding part can be hidden in the graph.
Or if I can achieve this purpose to hide parts of the graph otherwise, whether or not by clicking on the legend.

Thank you.

Comment: You can interact with the chart by clicking its items, but not the legend.

Comment: @Dan OK thanks, and...if I want to see the chart in full screen and making a scroll down to display the legend how do I can do?
Is that in graphs with many series with large legend, the chart looks very small ... thanks again.